# Different appenders per namespace

Tags: log4net

I'm trying to set up a common logging library which determines the `ILog` instance based on the current stack and what is the best instance of ILog to use.

I've got my config set up like this:

```xml
<log4net>
  <!-- appenders omitted -->
  <root></root>

  <logger name="MyAssembly.MyNamespace">
    <level value="WARN" />
    <!-- appender list -->
  </logger>
</log4net>
```

And I have a class like this:

```cs
namespace MyAssembly.MyNamespace.SubNamespace {
  public class MyClass { ... } 
}
```

When I try and get an instance of `ILog` I pass in the type (`var log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass)).Namespace);`) and I want it to detect that there isn't any logger configured, so it will then go up one level in the namespace tree (to `MyAssembly.MyNamespace`) and then see if it is configured at that point.

The problem is that the `ILog` returned for `MyAssembly.MyNamespace.SubNamespace` is configured for WARN events (and above), essentially what I configured for it's parent. Log4net seems to be returning the `ILog` when the required name **contains** a defined name, rather than when it **equals** the name.

How do I get Log4net to only return a *valid* logger when the name is the same as one defined in the config?

Comment: perhaps Dependency Injection of the logger instance would be a better design?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: True using something like MEF would be neat but we've got a DI-less implementation which I'm just trying to tweak

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`log4net` treats loggers as existing in a hierarchy based on their names, so the logger with name `MyAssembly.MyNamespace.SubNamespace` is a child of the logger with name `MyAssembly.MyNamespace`.

If no level (WARN etc.) is specified for a logger, the system traverses the logger hierarchy until it finds a logger with a configured level - and that becomes the effective level for that logger.

In your case, the child logger has no level specified, so it inherits the level of its parent - WARN. If you specify

```
<logger name="MyAssembly.MyNamespace.SubNamespace">
    <level value="DEBUG" /> <!-- or whatever -->
    <!-- no need to specify appenders, will use parent's -->
</logger>
```

then you will get DEBUG output from the child logger (sent to the appenders configured for the parent).